# maximum load of balls and bins when $m \neq n$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, binomial-distribution, balls-in-bins

When $m=n$, there is a classical result such that the maximum load would be $\theta(\frac{\ln n}{\ln \ln n})$. However, what happens when $m \neq n$? Say if $m = n^{0.5}$ or $m=n^{0.9}$, how can we analyze the max load in this case?

$m$ is the number of balls and $n$ is number of bins

Comment: Looks like you forgot to introduce $m$ and $n$.

Comment: @joriki, $m$ is number of balls and $n$ is number of bins

Answer (score 1):

The general asymptotic formula for any $m \leq n \log n$ is
$$
 \Theta \left( \frac{\log n}{\log \left( \frac{4n}{m} \cdot \log n\right)}\right),
$$
and for any $m \geq n \log n$ it is $$
  \frac{m}{n} + \Theta\left(\sqrt{\frac{m}{n} \cdot \log n} \right).
$$
Both of these hold in expectation and with probability at least $1 - n^{-\Omega(1)}$.

For the cases $m = n^{0.5}$ and $m = n^{0.9}$, that you mentioned, the maximum load is $\Theta(1)$ using the first formula.

For more information, see:

- [These notes](https://www.ic.unicamp.br/%7Ecelio/peer2peer/math/czumaj-balls-into-bins.pdf) by Artur Czumaj
- *“Balls into Bins” — A Simple and Tight Analysis* by Raab and Steger (1999)
- The books *Probability and Computing* by Mitzenmacher and Upfal (2017) and *Lecture notes on bucket algorithms* by Luc Devroye (1986)